# Si dos punteros apuntan a lo mismo, si borro un puntero. ¿El otro se borra o que pasa con el?

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo c++ y me encuentro con el siguiente código. En el veo que que llega un momento en el que **aux y a,ux2 apuntan a lo mismo** (ultimo else), en este condicional solo se borra aux2, pero aux no, porque da una clase de error. Entiendo que al borrar un puntero borra lo que apunta (a lo que referencia, y de paso dicho puntero "hablo de aux2"), pero en cuanto a aux **al principio pensaba que este seguiría existiendo pero no apuntaría a nada. Pero al parecer este también se borra cuando aux2 se elimina.**

Entonces... ¿Que es lo que esta pasando realmente con el puntero aux en memoria?

```
void pop(Nodo *&pila, int valor){
    Nodo *aux = pila;
    Nodo *aux2 = pila;
    bool flag = true;

    while(flag){
        if(aux2->valor != valor){
            aux = aux2;
            aux2 = aux2->siguiente;
        }
        else{
            aux->siguiente = aux2->siguiente;
            aux = aux2;
            delete aux2;
            flag = false;
            //delete aux; Da error si lo intento borrar, ¿Por que?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creo que tienes algunos conceptos no del todo claros:

```
int A = 10;
int B = 10;

B = 0;
```

¿ Que valor tendrá `A` ?

Efectivamente, `A` valdrá `10` porque **2 variables son totalmente independientes una de la otra**.

Pues con punteros pasa exactamente lo mismo:

```
int A = 10;
int *ptr1 = &A;
int *ptr2 = &A;

ptr2 = nullptr;
```

¿ Que valor tendrá `ptr1` ? Pues el que se le dio en su última asignación, es decir, la dirección de `A`.

Y ahora, una última pregunta:

```
int A = 10;
int *ptr1 = &A;
int *ptr2 = &A;

*ptr2 = 0;
ptr2 = nullptr;
```

¿ Que valor tendrá `ptr1` ? Pues como ya se ha visto, mantiene el valor de su última asignación: la dirección de `A`.

¿ Que valor tendrá `A` ? Pues el que se le dio en su última asignación, **que fue de forma indirecta** (`*ptr2 = 0`). Es decir, `A == 0`.

¿ Que valor tendrá `*ptr1` ? Pues el que se le dio en su última asignación, **que fue de forma indirecta** (`*ptr2 = 0`). Es decir, `*ptr1 == 0`.

Y, respondiendo a tu pregunta, el error lo obtienes porque **llamar a `delete` 2 veces sobre una misma dirección de memoria es un comportamiento indefinido**. Pero tienes que entender que `delete` **no trabaja sobre punteros**, sino **sobre la dirección a la que apuntan**. Y, puesto que `aux` y `aux2` *apuntaban* al mismo sitio, el resultado es el que ya has observado: error por liberación doble de memoria.

Ten presente que `comportamiento indefinido` significa que lo que pase no está indicado. Puede que funcione. Puede que provoque un error. Puede que funcione solo los días de luna llena. O puede que el error aparezca 45 minutos después de llamar a `delete`.