# ¿Si dos punteros apuntan a 2 direcciones de memoria, pueden hacerle cambios a otro puntero?

Tags: c++, punteros

Lo sé, tal vez el título no se entienda mucho, pero tranquilo, te lo trataré de explicar mejor adelante.

#### Ejemplo

Bueno, pongamos un ejemplo:

vamos a declarar 2 punteros, uno llamado "aux" y otro "lista":

```
nodo* lista = NuevoNodoDeListaEnlazada;

nodo* aux = lista;
```

Como algunos ya se han dado cuenta, estoy trabajando con listas enlazadas.

#### ¿Qué es "NuevoNodoDeListaEnlazada"? ¡No has explicado eso!

Eso simplemente es un nuevo nodo para una lista enlazada; <s>creo que no hizo falta explicar eso...</s>

#### Continuación

Bueno, sigamos con el ejemplo:

Bueno, aquí les dejo una parte de código (no es exactamente el código original):

```
 while(aux->siguiente != nullptr){
            aux = aux->siguienteNodoDeListaEnlazada;
        }
        
        aux->siguiente = NuevoNodoDeListaEnlazada;
```

Ahora aquí va mi pregunta: ¿qué pasará con el puntero "lista"? / ¿cómo demonios cambiará el puntero "lista"?

#### ¿Qué he intentado por ahora? / aclaraciones

Le eché un ojo a esta pregunta: [**Si dos punteros apuntan a lo mismo, si borro un puntero. ¿El otro se borra o que pasa con el?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/373265/si-dos-punteros-apuntan-a-lo-mismo-si-borro-un-puntero-el-otro-se-borra-o-que)

Y @Trauma respondió la pregunta, aunque no me ha quedada del todo clara la respuesta... Quisiera una respuesta un poquito más detallada.

#### Código completo

Para quien quiera ver todo el código fuente:

```
struct nodo{
    
    int dato;
    nodo* siguiente;
};

void insertarLista(nodo*& lista, int n){
    
    nodo* nuevoNodo = new nodo();
    
    nuevoNodo->siguiente = nullptr;
    nuevoNodo->dato = n;
    
    if(lista == nullptr){
        lista = nuevoNodo;
    }else{
        
        nodo* aux = lista;
        
        while(aux->siguiente != nullptr){
            aux = aux->siguiente;
        }
        
        aux->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> while(aux->siguiente != nullptr){
>     aux = aux->siguienteNodoDeListaEnlazada;
> }
>     
> aux->siguiente = NuevoNodoDeListaEnlazada;
> ```
>
> Ahora aquí va mi pregunta: ¿qué pasará con el puntero "lista"? / ¿cómo
> demonios cambiará el puntero "lista"?

Vamos a verlo con otro ejemplo, ¿Qué pasará con la variable `a`?

```
int a = 1;
int b = 1;

b = 7;
```

No le pasa absolutamente nada, son dos variables independientes. La única diferencia entre una variable *normal* es que un puntero almacena una dirección de memoria. Para el resto de características son exactamente iguales.

Lo que sucede con los punteros es que, al almacenar direcciones de memoria, pueden acceder, consultar y modificar los valores almacenados en dichas direcciones de memoria.

> Si dos punteros apuntan a lo mismo, si borro un puntero. ¿El otro se borra o que pasa con el?

Un puntero puede apuntar a una dirección de memoria que puede ser de la pila o del montón.

- La pila o *stack* es la memoria que pertence a la pila del programa. La gestión de esta memoria corre a cargo del propio programa y en ella se almacenan, por ejemplo, los objetos que se crean por valor.
- El montón o *heap* es la memoria dinámica en sí misma. Este saco engloba toda la memoria que el programa debe reservar haciendo uso de `new`, `malloc`, `calloc`, etc. El programador es el que debe encargarse de la gestión de esta memoria.

Pues bien, un puntero es, en el fondo, una variable, así que un puntero que declaremos tal que:

```
int* ptr = new int[5];
```

Se compone de dos partes:

- La memoria propia del puntero, es decir, en 64 bits serán 8 bytes, los cuales se usan para almacenar direcciones de memoria. Esta memoria se encontrará en la pila del programa
- La memoria direccionada por el puntero, en este caso 20 bytes (5 elementos de 4 bytes cada uno). Esta memoria se encuentra ubicada en el montón. El puntero almacenará en su memoria interna (8 bytes) la posición de memoria más baja del paquete.

Esta estructura viene a destacar un hecho importante, y es que los punteros **no se borran**, lo que hacemos es liberar la memoria direccionada por el puntero. La variable puntero como tal seguirá existiendo después del `delete` y podremos seguir usándola para direccionar más memoria ... lo que no podremos es seguir usando la memoria que acabamos de liberar.

Por exponerlo con un ejemplo:

```
// Declaramos un puntero y hacemos una reserva de memoria
int * a = new int(1); 

// Liberamos la memoria asociada al puntero
delete a;

// Podemos seguir usando el puntero sin problemas
a = new int(2);

// Declaramos un segundo puntero, ambos apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria
int* b = a;          

// Podemos trabajar indistintamente con cualquiera de los dos punteros
std::cout << *a << *b << '\n';

// Liberamos la memoria compartida por ambos punteros
delete a;

// Esta línea probablemente haga que el Sistema Operativo mate nuestro programa
std::cout << *b;
```

Comment: Wow, estaba tan simple entenderlo...